# usb keyboard messages

Tags: keyboard

I have bought a (DIGITECH XC-4943) multi-media keyboard. It has no manual and some of the keys are not labelled. Is there a utility (or some delphi code) I can use to display the messages that each key sends ?

Comment: The `xev` tool under X or `showkey` program under Linux console will report this information.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options depending on the OS you use.

First, you must know a few terms:
A `scancode` is the lowest identification number for a key. If a key does not have a scancode then we cannot do anything because it means that the kernel does not see it.
A `keycode` is the second level of identification for a key, a keycode corresponds to a function.
A `symbol` is the third level of identification for a key, it is the way Xorg refers to keys.

As a Linux user, you can use the `showkey` command in a TTY terminal to check for keycodes. Do not use this under a Terminal Emulator on Xorg. If you wish to use a Terminal Emulator, use the `xev` command from the `xorg-xev` package.

If you do not see a keycode on your screen against a keypress, you must take a chance with finding its scancodes and assigning a keycode to them.

Press the key on a TTY Terminal and then execute:

```
$ dmesg|tail -5
```

If you see something akin to this:

```
atkbd.c: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xf1 on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e071 <keycode>' to make it known.
```

You know that the kernel recognizes the keypress, but has no keycode assigned to it. Use the `setkeycodes` as mentioned to assign a keycode to the scancode.

**EDIT:** Let me know if you want more information on doing all this from within Xorg. Or for further information on creating and assigning special keys.